# Get user name of comment in comments table FQL

Tags: facebook-fql

I am getting Facebook comments data for particular posts using `FQL`. `FQL` returns only fromid however i need fromname as well. I am using batch request for getting comments of 50 posts at same time.

My query is

```
SELECT object_id,post_id,fromid,time,text,id,reply_xid,post_fbid,is_private FROM comment WHERE post_id='".$postID."'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It's probably a bug: 'username' is returning anonymous user now. Switching to graph api should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make an additional query, something like this:

```
    $multiQuery_postInfo = array(
        "posts" => "SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, message_tags, likes, comments, share_count, attachment, action_links, type FROM stream WHERE source_id=$pageID",
        "users" => "SELECT uid, username, first_name, last_name, profile_url, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT actor_id FROM %23posts)"
    );
```